# TypeError: dart.global.firebase.storage is not a function on Flutter web

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-web

I am facing this issue while working on Flutter web.
[image: Here is the error]

And in my index.html looks like this
[image: part of index.html]

Answer (score 0):

You have a '_' rather than a '-' in firebase-storage.js

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried with this solution but not worked.